# Could not save whole figure of barplot with long yticklabel

Tags: python, seaborn, savefig

I want to save a barplot, but found it was clipped when save it to a file.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set_theme(font_scale=1.6)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
g = sns.barplot(x="tip", y="day", data=tips)
g.set(yticklabels=['Thur','Fri','Sat','Very long long long long Sun'])
fig.savefig('1.png',dpi=400)
```

Here is the figure shown in jupyter notebook

[image]

However, the figure saved was looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `bbox_index='tight'` as a parameter and argument to `plt.savefig()`

```
fig.savefig('1.png',dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Great appreciate your help.